# Find two sum function in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to solve a problem in testdome online exam.

the question is Write a function that, given a list and a target sum, returns zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should return null.

here is my code , it is just 75% true and the 25% to time is exceed

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class TwoSum
{
    public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
    {
        var result = from n1 in list
                     from n2 in list
                     where n1 + n2 == sum
                     select new Tuple<int, int>(list.IndexOf(n1), list.IndexOf(n2));
        return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> indices = FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
        Console.WriteLine(indices.Item1 + " " + indices.Item2);
    }
}
```

you can copy paste my code in the online website and see the result.
can any one help me so we get 100% true. :D

https://www.testdome.com/Questions/Csharp/TwoSum/4318

Comment: if the elements should be distinct, then maybe you should add condition `n1 != n2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those cases where you need to come at the problem from a different approach.  Instead of doing a cross join of all the values and finding the first sum that matches, instead you want to make a lookup of all the values and loop through and check if the difference of the current item and the sum are in that lookup.  That way you get a worst case of linear performance instead of polynomial.

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    var lookup = list.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                     .ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Index);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int diff = sum - list[i];
        if (lookup.Contains(diff))
            return Tuple.Create(i, lookup[diff].First());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer but it doesn't work for TestDome, it exceed the memory usage limitation. Atif's answer works with some minor alteration.

Comment: I'm confused.  How is this linear?  Isn't the Contains method O(n) ?  Put that inside the for-loop makes it O(n^2)

Comment: @Joe the resulting `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` hashes on the key, so `Contains` is a O(1).  It's basically like a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TElement>>`.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for straightening me out on this.  This question has been a very popular interview question over the past year... and it even appeared on an on-line evaluation.

Comment: Jonny T's answer below currently passes 100% on TestDome

Comment: Why bother building the lookup? It's just unneeded overhead. It's an additional memory structure and, also, it doesn't terminate once a match is found. Just loop through the items.

Comment: @JonathanWood Because looping through the items would be O(n^2) instead of linear.  Typically memory is cheaper than time so trading memory for a faster algorithm is usually  a good trade off.

Answer (score 10):

A little bit modification from Atif's solution which we don't need to copy the list to HashSet firstly.

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var needed = sum - list[i];
        if (hs.Contains(needed))
        {
            return Tuple.Create(list.IndexOf(needed), i);
        }
        hs.Add(list[i]);                
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is 100% result including the "Performance test with a large number of elements" test

Answer (score 4):

A slight modification to your code by using a HashSet instead of a LookUp.

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<int>();
    list.ToList().ForEach(x => hs.Add(x));

    for (int i = 0; i < hs.Count; i++)
    {
        var diff = sum - list[i];
        if (hs.Contains(diff))
        {
            var index = list.IndexOf(diff);
            return new Tuple<int, int>(i, index);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

> I have tried and tested and get 100%, i.e. all tests pass including the
>   "Performance test with a large number of elements" test

Comment: Imho this code isn't correct. You loop over the count of the hashset (for (int i = 0; i < hs.Count; i++))  and look the value of that index up in the list (var diff = sum - list[i];). If list contains many duplicates and the answer is not in the first few values this will not find an anwser. It should be var diff = sum - hs.ElementAt(i);

Comment: Doesn't a hashset contain unique elements so you wouldn't have duplicates?

Comment: This gives 25%. Can you explain how you got 100%?

Comment: This one works for TestDome, just need to add in a check to make sure the indices aren't the same.
"if (hs.Contains(diff) && i != list.IndexOf(diff))"

Comment: Just a minor issue, but using `ToList` just so you can use `ForEach` is a waste when you can just use a normal `foreach`.

Comment: Jonny T's answer below currently passes 100% on TestDome

Answer (score 4):

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int target)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var diff = target - list[i];
        int j = -1;
        if(dict.TryGetValue(diff, out j))
        {
            return Tuple.Create<int, int>(j, i);
        }

        dict[list[i]] = i;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This solution got 100% on TestDome

Answer (score 3):

This is my working solution:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        var aim = sum - list[i];

        if(dictionary.ContainsKey(aim))
        {
            return new Tuple<int, int> (dictionary[aim], i);
        }
        else if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(list[i]))
        {
            dictionary.Add(list[i], i);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification to your version also passes the test. It is not 100% correct though. That tells you test cases on Testdome are not complete. I will leave it as an exercise as to what is wrong.

```
    public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
    {
        var result = from n1 in list
                     join n2 in list
                     on n1 equals sum - n2
                     select new Tuple<int, int>(list.IndexOf(n1), list.IndexOf(n2));
        return result.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Item1!=x.Item2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

a non Linq extensions method using version of juharr's code

```
    public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSumImprovedNonLinq(IList<int> list, int sum)
    {          
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int diff = sum - list[i];
            if (list.IndexOf(diff) > -1)
                return Tuple.Create(i, list.IndexOf(diff));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This was helpful to understand :)

Comment: This does not work for this test case: FindTwoSumImprovedNonLinq(new List<int>() { 2, 7, 1, 3 }, 4); (it returns 0 0). If statement must also check list.IndexOf(diff) != i. But even with that TestDome gives 75% due to performance test case failure.

Comment: @MeetingAttender looks like only a hashset bases solution will pass all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    int max = list.Max();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        int first = list[i];

        if (first + max == sum) return new Tuple<int, int>(i, list.IndexOf(max));

        if (first + max < sum) continue;

        for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            int second = list[j];
            if (sum == first + second)
            {
                return new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that passes all 4 tests. There's abuncha issues about the problem, however, that make it interesting. Basic test: iterate through a list, for each number in the list, iterate through the list and find its pair, ie that which when added together equal the target value. So it's O(n**2) algorithm. The 4th test burns that down. A big hint here, you only have to return the first matching pair. So, to solve:

- double iterate through the list and return solution
- special case for null list
- special case for no solution found
- special case for entry which when doubled equals the target: they must have a different index. eg:({5,1,3}, 10) 5+5=10, however, there must be a second 5, so this fails, where ({5,1,3,5},10) succeeds returning (0,3)
- So, to kick the algorithm down to O(n), we can keep a record of what #s we've found, because we only need to keep the 1st occurrence of each one. But, we need a flexible, fast, data structure to do it. Array fails because we don't know what size it will be at compile time. I tried List. So you have 10million ones, it saves the first list[0]=1, and charges on. Next is 2, 2+1!=10, add 2 to list, move on. Works.
- until you have an input of 10million sequential ints, and the list is huge. So switch to Dictionary. Now it passes all 4 tests.

So, sequence through input list, for each item, search its pair in the dictionary. If not, search this item in dictionary, if not, add it. When you do find its pair in the dictionary, set your return and go.

```
public class Item
{
    public Item(int _val, int _loc) {
        val = _val;
        loc = _loc;
    }
    public int val;
    public int loc;
}
class TwoSum
{
    public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
    {
        Tuple<int, int> result = null;
        Dictionary<int, Item> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Item>();
        int index = 0; 
        bool done = false;

        do
        {
            int curr = list[index];
            int pair = sum - list[index];

            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(pair))
            {
                result = new Tuple<int, int>(index, dictionary[pair].loc);
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (! dictionary.ContainsKey(curr))
                {
                    Item found1 = new Item(curr, index);
                    dictionary.Add(curr, found1);
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
        while (index < list.Count && !done);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A even simpler way is:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
      // subtract the item to the sum to find the difference
        int diff = sum - list[i];

      // if that number exist in that list find its index
        if (list.Contains(diff))
        {
            return Tuple.Create(i, list.IndexOf(diff));
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

That way you wouldn't need to lookup the entire list in advance, it still is a 75% though.

Comment: This will not work for FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 2, 7, 1, 3 }, 4);

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 3 };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        var requiredElements = arr.Select((item, index) => new { index, item }).Where(ind => ind.item.Equals(4 - arr[i])).ToList();

        if (requiredElements.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var disp in requiredElements)

                Console.WriteLine("Indexes are " + i.ToString() + ":" + disp.index);  
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

// Where  4 is the target into - ind.item.Equals(4 - arr[i])

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. As far as I test, It returns right indices. But I don't know if it is efficient for performance.

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        int difference = sum - list[i];
        bool isExist = list.Contains(difference);
        if (!isExist)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (difference == list[i] && list.Where(x => x == difference).ToList().Count > 1)
        {
            var duplicated = list.Select((item, index) => new { Value = item, Index = index }).Where(x => x.Value == difference).Take(2).ToList();
            return new Tuple<int, int>(duplicated[0].Index, duplicated[1].Index);
        }
        else if (difference == list[i] && list.Where(x => x == difference).ToList().Count == 1) continue;
        else
        {
            return new Tuple<int, int>(i, list.IndexOf(difference));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit:
My first solution has a huge performance problem. So I decided to improve Mohammed Turshan's solution. I think it has duplication bug. I solved that problem by using Dictionary class.

```
    public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> dict = list.Select((value, index) => 
    new { Value = value, Index = index }).ToDictionary(x => x.Index, x => x.Value);

    var result = from n1 in dict
                 from n2 in dict
                 where n1.Value + n2.Value == sum && n1.Key != n2.Key
                 select new Tuple<int, int>(n1.Key, n2.Key);

    return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, building a lookup table is just extra memory and overhead. In addition, it processes every item in the list rather than stopping when a match is found.

So why not just something like this?

```
public Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(IList<int> list, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++)
        {
            if (list[i] + list[j] == sum)
                return new Tuple<int, int>(list[i], list[j]);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone needs Java Solution

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> numAndIndex = new HashMap<>();
    for(int currentIndex=0; currentIndex<nums.length; currentIndex++){
        
        int currentNumber=nums[currentIndex];
        Integer expectedIndex=numAndIndex.get(target-currentNumber);
        
        if(expectedIndex!=null){
            return new int[]{expectedIndex, currentIndex};
        }
        numAndIndex.put(currentNumber, currentIndex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score -2):

public static Tuple FindTwoSum(IList list, int sum)
        {

```
        for(int i=0;i<list.Count;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<list.Count;j++)
            {
                if((list[i]+list[j])==12)
                {
                    return new Tuple<int, int>(i,j);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
```

}

This will work

Comment: In it's current form, the solution only works for 2/4 test cases. Changing `if((list[i]+list[j])==12)` to `if((list[i]+list[j])==sum)` works for 3/4 cases. It still fails for the 4th case: `Performance test with a large number of elements: Time limit exceeded`.

Comment: It takes O(n2) time which is inefficient.we. An do this using hashset in O(n) time